# Export var in nodejs which contains the creation of the connection to MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

I need to export this to use it in other files of my project. Thank you.

I tried to export with module.exports and import it with required in other files but when it fails. mysql is not defined.

```
var myConnection = mysql.createConnection({

    host: "192.168.1.50",
    user: "pi",
    password: "root"
});
```

I hope you help me to take these variables to other parts of my project.

Comment: are you sure `myConnection` has the actual value you want? Usually you will have a _Promise_ in that variable

Comment: Actually this variable is an example, what I really want is to know how to export this type of variables. That is, "var x = mysql. * ({// my code});"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using ES6 imports/exports

To export your variable, do it like this

```
// exportFile.js
export const myConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "192.168.1.50",
    user: "pi",
    password: "root"
});
```

To import it in another file, use this

```
// importerFile.js
import { myConnection } from './exporterFile';
```

## Using `require`

Export like this using `module.exports`

```
// exportFile.js
module.exports = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "192.168.1.50",
    user: "pi",
    password: "root"
});
```

To import it in another file, use this

```
// importerFile.js
const myConnection = require('./exporterFile');
```

Comment: when ago that I get this error in the console: /                                          
import { myConnection } from './connectio';
           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:84:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:264:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:312:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:694:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566: ....

Comment: try using the `require` syntax I've added in the edit

Comment: Thank you very much I have already solved it, the problem is that mysql is not importing the external file thank you very much.

Comment: glad to be of help!